# Google Maps JavaScript Places API - URL undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am integrating the Google Maps API into a website I am working on. For the most part, it performs as desired; however, when making a call to the nearbySearch service, I am having difficulty getting the url (to the Google Maps page for the location) returned. According to my understanding of the Google documentation, this call returns a PlaceResult object with various properties, including url.I am able to access two other properties, name and vicinity, properly, but the url property is coming back as undefined. What might the issue be? Thanks.

The relevant code snippet:

```
var keyword =  document.getElementById("searchBox").value;
var requestOptions = {
location: { lat: 37.3011339, lng: -89.5770238},
radius: '5000',
keyword: keyword
};

placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(hotelMap);
placesService.nearbySearch(requestOptions, findCallback);

});

}; // end initiallize

function findCallback(results, status) {

var resultsList = "";


  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

       alert(results[i].url); // this returns undefined           
     resultsList += "<li>" + results[i].name + ": " + results[i].vicinity + " - <a href='" + results[i].url + "'>View Details</a></li>";

    }

    document.getElementById("searchList").innerHTML = resultsList;



  } 
}
```

For reference:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceResult

Comment: Test in more locations?  The places you are looking at may not actually have google pages? Or, use the website object and only show if available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that property isn't available in the `PlaceResult` returned in the `nearbySearch` query.  A details request on the placeIds from the results returned by that query, returns results with that property available.

Per my reading of the documentation, the only query that should return a "limited" `PlaceResult` is `radarSearch`, but that doesn't seem to be the way it is working.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gf6hrzeg/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var hotelMap;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function initialize() {
  hotelMap = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var keyword = document.getElementById("searchBox").value;
  var requestOptions = {
    location: {
      lat: 37.3011339,
      lng: -89.5770238
    },
    radius: '5000',
    keyword: keyword
  };

  placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(hotelMap);
  placesService.nearbySearch(requestOptions, findCallback);

}; // end initiallize

function findCallback(results, status) {
  var resultsList = "";
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      console.log(results[i].url);
      console.log(results[i]);
      resultsList += "<li>" + results[i].name + ": " + results[i].vicinity + " - <a href='" + results[i].url + "'>View Details</a></li>";
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: results[i].geometry.location,
        map: hotelMap,
        title: results[i].name,
        placeId: results[i].place_id
      });
      bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker) {
        return function(evt) {
          var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(hotelMap);
          service.getDetails({
            placeId: this.placeId
          }, function(place, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
              var content = '<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
                'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
                place.formatted_address + '<br>';
              if (place.url) {
                content += '<a href=' + place.url + ' target="_blank">[link]</a>';
              }
              content += '</div>';
              infowindow.setContent(content);
              infowindow.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
              infowindow.open(hotelMap, marker);
            }
          });
        }
      })(marker));
    }
    hotelMap.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
  document.getElementById("searchList").innerHTML = resultsList;
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<input id="searchBox" value="coffee" />
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<div id="searchList"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough insight. I wish it were not so (that is, nearbySearch returned a PlacesResult with the url property), but obviously there is not much we can do about it. Again, thanks for your discovery.